# How to generate dynamic for loop

Tags: c#, loops, dynamic, for-loop

There are 5 cascading combo boxes in a page which are dynamically created. 
I have to do something when the desired sum is achieved. This is my code which generates some output; I want to generate all the for loops and even the all 'cmb' arrays dynamically. How can I   achieve it?

```
private int[] cmb1 = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 20 };
private int[] cmb2 = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 20 };
private int[] cmb3 = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 20 };
private int[] cmb4 = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 20 };
private int[] cmb5 = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 20 };
int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < cmb1.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cmb2.Length; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < cmb3.Length; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < cmb4.Length; l++)
                    {
                        for (int m = 0; m < cmb5.Length; m++)
                        {
                            if (cmb1[i] + cmb2[j] + cmb3[k] + cmb4[l] + cmb5[m] <= 20 && (i + j + k + l + m) != 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(count + " _ " + i + " " + j + " " + k + " " + l + " " + m);
                                count = count + 1;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamically'?

Comment: the cmb's may change time to time, so that for loops also to be changed...

Comment: the length of the cmb's? or type

Comment: on the "even all 'cmb' arrays dynamically" try using a multidimensional array instead of a literal array of arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by "the cmb's may change"? You might add a `cmb6`, or remove `cmb5`, etc?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes there may be n no of cmb's like cmb1, cmb2...cmbn

Comment: use a List<List<int>> and iterate it

Comment: pls give me the example

Comment: I think at this point we need to know what you're actually trying to do with this code before we can help you modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll direct you to [Eric Lippert's excellent article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) on implementing a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) in Linq, which he wrote as a [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx):

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
    // base case: 
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
    foreach(var sequence in sequences) 
    { 
        var s = sequence; // don't close over the loop variable 
        // recursive case: use SelectMany to build the new product out of the old one 
        result = 
          from seq in result 
          from item in s 
          select seq.Concat(new[] {item}); 
    } 

    return result; 
}
```

So in your code you would call it like this:

```
private List<int[]> cmbs = new List<int[]>();

...

// build cmbs list
cmbs.Add(cmb1);
cmbs.Add(cmb2);
cmbs.Add(cmb3);
cmbs.Add(cmb4);
cmbs.Add(cmb5);

// loop through cmbs
var count = 0;
foreach(var result in cmbs.CartesianProduct().Skip(1)) // Skip the first result
{
    if (result.Sum() <= 20) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(count + "_" + String.Join(" ", result));
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get the solution without CartesianProduct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SateeshKumar What you're asking for *is* a [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Is there something in particular that's wrong with this solution?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in that, as per my requirement I need solution without CartesianProduct. please help me

Comment: @SateeshKumar I'm afraid I still don't understand what you're asking. If you want to do this without actually calling the `CartesianProduct` method, just copy the source from either my or *Servy*'s answer and execute it directly.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking to do can be considered the Cartesian Product of an unknown (at compile time) number of sequences.

Eric Lippert wrote a [blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/) about how to create such a solution in C#.  The code he ends up generating is:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
        from accseq in accumulator
        from item in sequence
        select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
}
```

Using this we can now do:

```
List<int[]> cmbs = new List<int[]>();
cmbs.Add(new int[] { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 20 });
cmbs.Add(new int[] { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 20 });
cmbs.Add(new int[] { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 20 });

var query = cmbs.CartesianProduct()
    .Where(combo => combo.Sum() <= 20 && combo.Sum() > 0);

int count = 0;
foreach (var combo in query)
{
    Console.Write((count++) + " _ ");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", combo));
}
```